# Regex to wrap text in html tags

Tags: regex, wordpress, translation

I'm trying to use a regex to wrap all text strings in php file with [`_e('')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) function. The text can be wrapped in all kinds of tags (span, p, div,..) and can contain newlines.

Do you have any ideas how to accomplish that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want those tags to work as html, or do you want them to be treated as regular text?

Comment: Don't use a regex; use an HTML parser - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1212596

Comment: Great reference, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)